# How to use Hugging Face sentiment analysis for a specified subject in a sentence?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-transformers

When using Hugging Face for sentiment analysis, it looks like you get the sentiment for a sentence as a whole. However if you have a sentence that compares 2 subject and one surpasses the other, it would look at the sentence as a whole. But the sentiment of one subject would be more positive while the other would be more negative.

Example:

> 'People enjoy Hagen Dazs over Breyers'

That's good for Hagen Dazs, but bad for Breyers. Hugging Face returns "Positive".

> 'You should buy Hagen Dazs instead of Breyers'

Hugging Face returns "Negative" here which would apply to Breyers but not Hagen Dazs.

```
# Example script using the above text
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
classifier('People enjoy Hagen Dazs over Breyers')

>> [{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9575461745262146}]

classifier('You should buy Hagen Dazs instead of Breyers')

>> [{'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9988893270492554}]
```

Is is possible to specify the topic to get the sentiment for in a sentence?

Comment: The discipline is called aspect-based sentiment analysis. You can find some repositories with the search engine of your choice. As far as I know, huggingface does not provide a pipeline for it.